# Array field parsed from JSON is empty

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I don't understand why this happens. I'm consuming REST service via WCF. In case of error the service sends this kind of message body (I see in Fiddler):

```
{"Errors":["Some text"],"StatusCode":500}
```

I have created a class for this, and getting it via Message.GetBody(). StatusCode is filled, but Errors are always empty (not null, but empty). I have tried String[], List of String, also tried initialized backing field. What is wrong here?

Here is the class:

```
[DataContract(Name="root", Namespace="")]
public class ErrorResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string[] Errors { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Errors);
    }
}
```

Here is the parsing:

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    var resp = reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
    if (resp != null && resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        String message = null;
        try
        {
            ErrorResult res = reply.GetBody<ErrorResult>();
            if (res != null)
            {
                message = res.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch { }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `[DataContract(Name="root", Namespace="")]` because I was getting error "expecting element ErrorResult with namespace 'bla-bla-bla' but got element 'root' with namespace ''".

**UPDATE**. I have noticed the same problem with another entity, the one which was service result type. It contained 2 integer fields, and on return they were 0s, even though I could see in Fiddler and in Message.ToString() values there. I have fixed this by adding Name="..." to DataMember attributes, even though those names are the same as property names, except casing (JSON camel vs C# pascal). I was sure that C# parsing is case insensitive! Ok, but adding names to ErrorResult in subject still didn't fix the problem with array.

**UPDATE 2**. Ok, after not finding any solution, I did a workaround in an "ugly way". At least this started working at once.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(reply.ToString());
String message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    doc.SelectNodes("/root/Errors/item").OfType<XmlNode>().Select(n => n.InnerText));
```

I have also tried XMlSerialzer with Message.GetReaderAtBodyContents(), but got "error in XML" and gave it up.

Comment: there are several properties like `FaultExceptionsEnabled`,`HelpEnabled` & `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` you can enable in config.Have you tried?

Comment: Amit, I have checked these and they don't look applicable. FaultExceptionsEnabled must be server config, and I am on client side. Just to check, I've set it for client's behavior, and the result was no exception at all! Using [FaultContract] and catching FaultException of T gave me hope, but unfortunately that didn't work. I'm getting CommunicationException if I don't get detailed info from the message earlier. I don't have control over server, only over client.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why are you using WCF to *consume* a REST service?   Just use `HttpClient` or something similar.  And since you're receiving JSON, why not use a JSON Serializer/Deserializer, like JSON.NET?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/collection-in-wcf/) is explained what to do to make List work. I usually use arrays (eg: string[] not Array class) to avoid problems or additional configuration and cast on client side.

Comment: The problem is not with List, this is just what I tried. Initally, I have used string[] also, and the result was the same. I have modified the question to avoid confusion.